# Using Array.Sub with pipeline operator

Tags: f#

Below is a working samle of [Array.sub](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/array.sub%5B%27t%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) in `F#`

```
let a1 = [| 0 .. 99 |]
let a2 = Array.sub a1 5 10
printfn "%A" a2
```

I tried using the pipeline operator `|>` by neither this code worked with me:

```
a1 |> Array.sub 5 10
```

Neither this:

```
a1 5 10 ||> Array.sub
```

Is there a possible way?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operator `|>` sends the **last** argument of the function.

So it will be:

```
10 |> Array.sub a1 5
```

In the other case, it's the last 2 arguments, but they should be sent in a tuple:

```
(5, 10) ||> Array.sub a1
```

Here's another option which might be closer to what you're looking for:

```
a1 |> Array.sub <|| (5, 10)
```

Comment: Super smart elegant answer, thanks a lot `a1 |> Array.sub <|| (5, 10)`

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that the `Array.sub` function has this order of arguments for compatibility reasons. The order is the same in [OCaml version](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Array.html) which is what F# started with a long time ago. This is a bit unfortunate, because it means that the function is not very well suited for piping.

I would probably define a new function that just reverses the order of arguments. Note that you can define your own `Array` module and so you'll see it along with all other array functions:

```
module Array = 
  let subArray lo hi arr = Array.sub arr lo hi
```

Now you can use `Array.subArray` in a pipeline without using other pipeline-like operators that (in my humble opinion) make code much harder to read:

```
let something = 
  [| 0 .. 99 |]
  |> Array.map (fun x -> x * 2)
  |> Array.subArray 5 10
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think the other one is more straight forward, but I learned from your answer as well :)